# Reading Server Directories v/s XML File for photo album pages

Tags: php, xml, json, data-structures, datalist

To load a list of portfolio items (like photo albums), is it appropriate to read server directory every time page loads? Or an accompanying XML/JSON file should be created?

Current solution uses simple directory structure like following:

```
portfolio/CategoryA
portfolio/CategoryB
portfolio/CategoryA/1.Title.Subtitle
portfolio/CategoryA/5.Title.Subtitle
portfolio/CategoryA/6.Title.Subtitle
portfolio/CategoryB/2.Title.Subtitle
portfolio/CategoryB/3.Title.Subtitle
portfolio/CategoryB/4.Title.Subtitle
```

Directory names are dot-separated; having sort-order, title and subtitle for each page.

Each of the above directories contains image files, which are again directory-read to generate HTML (with PHP):

```
portfolio/CategoryA/1.Title.Subtitle/cover.jpg
portfolio/CategoryA/1.Title.Subtitle/01.jpg
portfolio/CategoryA/1.Title.Subtitle/02.jpg
portfolio/CategoryA/1.Title.Subtitle/03.jpg
```

Now we are implementing Previous/Next links in each page, which means that whole server directory structure will have to be read not only to generate a list of albums, but also for each inside page. What are the performance implications of this approach?

**Instead, an XML/JSON file can be kept with a sorted list of all directories. The question is which one is the correct, optimal approach? Parsing an XML or reading server directories?**

In case it is relevant, this is hosted on a shared Linux server.

Comment: After you read the XML, you're still decoding it and loading the information from it from disk? including images etc.

Comment: @vlzvl XML file is to be used for storing list of directories only (so as to avoid traversing directory every time), no other metada.

However XML can include number of files inside each directory. It makes generating inner pages easier. e.g. If XML says there are 3 images in a directory, it would mean there will be 01.jpg, 02.jpg and 03.jpg there.

Other metadata, e.g. description, SEO tags etc. are stored as text files inside each directory. XML list file has nothing to do with it, it is just an auto-generated list file.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing xml allows you to "hide" the dir structure of your site,

say you have :
portfolio/CategoryA/1.Title.Subtitle

if a user finds out the structure of folders on your server he can access all the other users's files (even if you have private galleries for example) by going to the absolute url of the file.

us xml or some other method of masking images/userdata.

Comment: Do you mean open directory index? I think that can be avoided by putting an index.html file inside each directory which redirects to home page.

The directories need to remain readable to visitor because images are linked from there in HTML.

There are no private galleries.

The idea is to keep it as easy as possible for website owners to update the gallery, which is also not too frequent, around 2 times a month, and keep it optimal for the server.